# Sublime Text2 Bracket Highlighter , highlight a html TAG

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I need to edit the plugin **brackethighlighter** to achieve following jpeg's effect.
on a html tag, like P,div,span tag and etc.

[image]

But my current setting had set the tag to highlight, but its still appear dotted line like the 3rd images, and i also already set the

[image]

and this is the setting on my theme

[image]

But i still get following dotted line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you have Djaneiro installed then you have to change the filetype to HTML from HTML Djaneiro.